# What is the purpose of ngForTrackBy in the NgForOf directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ngfor

From the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts) of Angular, the following snippet is confusing me.

```
 /**
   * A function that defines how to track changes for items in the iterable.
   *
   * When items are added, moved, or removed in the iterable,
   * the directive must re-render the appropriate DOM nodes.
   * To minimize churn in the DOM, only nodes that have changed
   * are re-rendered.
   *
   * By default, the change detector assumes that
   * the object instance identifies the node in the iterable.
   * When this function is supplied, the directive uses
   * the result of calling this function to identify the item node,
   * rather than the identity of the object itself.
   *
   * The function receives two inputs,
   * the iteration index and the node object ID.
   */
  @Input()
  set ngForTrackBy(fn: TrackByFunction<T>) {
    ...
      }
    }
    this._trackByFn = fn;
  }
```

And [here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#summary) in an example from the official docs where the `trackBy` function is passed.

```
trackById(index: number, hero: Hero): number { return hero.id; }
```

The source code explains that

> When this function is supplied, the directive uses the result of calling this function to identify the item node, rather than the identity of the object itself.

But in the example above, we are passing the identity of the object itself anyway (`return hero.id;`), but through an additional function. Why do we need that? If we did not pass any such function, wouldn't Angular do what it does by default as per the docs, which is, getting the identity of the object itself?

What exactly does the explicit passing of a tracker function do differently than what Angular does normally without it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular will check the reference in memory for a non primitive type.  If you don't pass the `trackById` method in, every time the array changes it thinks every object is new and recreates all the DOM nodes.

If pass it `trackById`, it will check the original object with the new object, and if their `id` properties are the same, it says they are the same object and it won't re-drawn that DOM node.

Here's an example you can run as well, which is just plain javascript

```js
let obj1 = {id: 1, name: 'test'};
let obj1a = {id: 1, name: 'test'};
let prim1 = 1;
let prim2 = 1;

const checkById = (a, b) => {
  return a.id === b.id;
}

// obj1 and 1a are not the same, because they are different references in memory
console.log("obj1 === obj1a", obj1 === obj1a);

// ob1 and obj1a are the "same" to us though, because the ID property is the same
console.log("checkById(obj1, obj1a)", checkById(obj1, obj1a));

// primitives would be equal
console.log("prim1 === prim2", prim1 === prim2);
```

Comment: So if I am getting this right, this is similar to the Vue syntax of `<li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>`
Except in the case of Angular I have to define a tracking function that returns the index by which the DOM nodes should be tracked.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue, but my guess there is that it has a built in method for doing this same thing by providing a key so it can compare those 2 values.  Angular has you provide a custom function to run, and while I've only used it to compare it by that objects "key", maybe there are other properties or multiple properties or some other logic you want to check as well so this allows for more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I can definitely see how the wording of that could be confusing.  But when it says "rather than the identity of the object itself" << it means the entire object.  In the case of that example, the entire hero object would be tracked by default.  By supplying it with a tracking function you can narrow it down to just one property of the object (e.g. the id property), rather than it tracking the entire object.  What might not be clear from that snippet, is the Hero class has some property named id.